# When does a new question appear in the list of the questions?

Tags: support, questions

I noticed that when I ask a new question, it doesn't appear immediately on the list of questions (e.g. https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions).

Does the question appear after X minutes, or does it appear depending on some other factors? I noticed that when I see my question in the list of the questions, the number of views is always higher than 1 (normally, 2). Is this one of those factors?